# Do I need to get dummies for "binary" categorical columns?

Tags: linear-model, scikit-learn, binary-data, categorical-encoding

My question is about a multi-variate linear regression model. I am experimenting with Python's `sklearn` library with the Ames Housing data set: http://jse.amstat.org/v19n3/decock/DataDocumentation.txt.

Do I need to dummy-encode a binary categorical variable? The variable is similar to a yes/no question. Most variables actually imply the absence of a characteristic. For example, "Wood Deck SF" and the porch type columns "[type] Porch SF" would only be either a positive value or 0. I already manually changed the column to have the values 1 and 0. Also, I read in ["Dummy Coding: The How and Why"](https://www.statisticssolutions.com/dummy-coding-the-how-and-why/) that:

> we do not use all three categories in a regression. Doing so
> would give the regression redundant information, result in
> multicollinearity, and break the model. This means we have to leave
> one category out, and we call this missing category the reference
> category.

I am aware that "categroical" varaibles/features need to be dummy coded. Dummy coding avoids idiotic or chance-based coefficients being assigned to Lickert scale answers or choices between items like 1, 2, and 3. However, given that article and the fact that I have already manually transformed the column into 1's and 0's, do I need to use `pd.get_dummies` on those binary categorical columns? I am confident I do not, but is there some detail I am missing, maybe a dataset- or python-specific detail that changes the proper procedure?

Comment: NO, a binary variable is already identical to the result of dummy-coding it!

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen OK, thanks. Are the links I posted enough third-party evidence to confirm your answer? I assume they are. I'll use your comment as my own answer to the question later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> BlockquoteNO, a binary variable is already identical to the result of dummy-coding it!
> – Kjetil B. Halvorsen

This comment can be proven if you actually revert the binary categorical variable and then apply pd.get_dummies to it. It will have the same effect as manually encoding the variables as ones and zeroes.